# What is the expected payoff of this game?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> I wager 100 Galactic Credits.  In each of two independent event, I have a $25\%$ chance of doubling my money.  If I win either the first or the second event, then I walk away with 200 Galactic Credits; if I win both events, I walk away with 400 Galactic Credits; and if I lose both events I walk away with nothing.  What is the expected payoff of this game?

The chance to double my money the first or second time: $2 \times (25\% \times 75\%) = 37.5\%$.

So, $37.5\%$ of the time I would walk away with 200 credits, on average 75 credits. Correct?

The chance to double my money the first and the second time is $25\% \times 25\% = 6.25\%$, however I'm getting my return twice, so I would walk away with 400 credits $6.25\%$ of the time, on average, 25 credits.

So can it be that I have a $43.75\%$ chance to win at all, but because of the payout of the double win, a $50\%$ chance to double my money? Such that, on average, I walk away with an even 100 credits on average?

What am I missing, if anything?

Comment: What happens if you lose the first chance to double your money? Do you have $0$ or still $100$?

Comment: If I understand your experiment correctly, you could model it with a single roll of two four sided dice.  You double your money if exactly one die comes up 4 (in your experiment, this corresponds to winning either the first time or the second time, but not both), and you quadruple your money if both die come up 4.  Do I understand your experiment properly?

Comment: @kccu - the two chances are built in. I thought I was clear when I said "if I lose both, I walk away with nothing"

Comment: @XanderHenderson - I think that's right, yes.

Comment: @HDS You have specified what happens if you lose both, but it's not clear what happens if you lose the first. A typical "double your money" gamble says you either double it or you walk away with nothing. Your setup seems to be that on the first gamble you either double it or walk away with $100$, while on the second gamble you either double your money or walk away with $0$. That's why I wanted to clarify.

Comment: @kccu Sorry if I wasn't clear. It's "two throws at the milk jugs" at the carnival or two dice, as Xander said, or - two 25% chances to double my money for a single $100 bet.

Comment: @HDS Then I think your calculations are spot on.

Comment: From your  description it sounds like there are two events, either of which will double your money. That is: you will double your money if either of these two events happen ... meaning that if both events happen, you still only double your money once. No?

Comment: @Bram28 - That can be your question. :) In mine, if you win both, you take home 400.

Comment: @HDS On the basis of your feedback to my comment, I have edited your question to clarify the rules of the game.  I also added the [tag:proof-verification] tag, which is, I think, appropriate for this question (you have a solution, and want to know if it is correct).  Please feel free to undo the edits if you are unhappy with them.

Comment: OK! Got it. Then you calculated it correctly.

Comment: Your analysis is correct.  You are confusing the expectation, which is the average money you make and is $0$, with the chance you win money, which is $43.75\%$.  The chance you win money being less than $50\%$ does not mean it is a losing bet.  In this case, when you win (some of the time) you win more than you lose.  It can work the other way as well.  The martingale systems at roulette give you a high chance of winning but a negative expectation overall because the losses are so large when they happen.

Answer (score 1):

The analysis in the question appears to be correct, but it is phrased in a way which I find to be a little confused and hard to follow.  Another way of thinking of this problem is to simulate it with two four-sided dice.  If you wager 100 Galactic Credits ($\mathfrak{G}$), then the payoffs are given by:

\begin{matrix}
\text{Exactly One $4$:}\hfill & \hfill 200\ \mathfrak{G} & (1)\\
\text{Exactly Two $4$s:}\hfill & \hfill 400\ \mathfrak{G} & (2)\\
\text{Anything Else:}\hfill & \hfill 0\ \mathfrak{G} & (3)
\end{matrix}

The expected payoff is then
$$ (200\ \mathfrak{G}) \cdot P(\text{Event (1)})
+ (400\ \mathfrak{G}) \cdot P(\text{Event (2)})
+ (0\ \mathfrak{G}) \cdot P(\text{Event (3)}). \tag{$\ast$}$$

There are a total of 16 possible rolls (the first die can be any number from $1$ to $4$, and the second die can be any number from $1$ to $4$).  Event (1) (exactly one $4$) can happen in $6$ different ways:  the first die comes up $4$, and the second die can be any of the remaining three numbers; and vice versa.  Therefore
$$ P(\text{Event (1)})
 = \frac{\text{Good Outcomes}}{\text{Total Outcomes}}
 = \frac{6}{16}
 = 0.375.
$$
Event (2) can happen in only one way:  both dice must come up $4$.  Hence
$$ P(\text{Event (2)})
 = \frac{\text{Good Outcomes}}{\text{Total Outcomes}}
 = \frac{1}{16}
 = 0.0625.
$$
We could compute the probability of Event (3), but since it is being multiplied by a payoff of $0\ \mathfrak{G}$ in ($\ast$), it is not important to do so.  That is, the term doesn't matter, so we aren't going to spend any more time on it.  Substituting these results into ($\ast$) gives
$$ (200\ \mathfrak{G}) \cdot \frac{6}{16} + (400\ \mathfrak{G})\cdot \frac{1}{16}
= \frac{1200 + 400}{16}\ \mathfrak{G}
= 100\ \mathfrak{G}.$$
That is, on average, you break even (you started with 100 Galactic Credits, and walk away with 100 Galactic Credits).

Comment: Great - thanks!